# Why does an fftshift in the time domain give a different result compared to the frequency domain?

Tags: matlab, fft, discrete-signals

I am trying to speed up some of my code and for physical reasons I need to do an FFT shift to get the FFT data in the standard DFT fourier representation. In Matlab this is performed in the frequency domain, with a data swap.

I had believed that I found a numerical trick, by performing the shift in the time domain, before transformation I was able to save a reasonable amount of computation time.

The problem is that for some reason the results are slightly different. I am curious as to why.

The Matlab code is as follows for a 1K signal

```
%1khz
f=1000;
t=0:.0001:5;
x=sin(2*pi*f*t);
%Wave
subplot(4,1,1);
plot(x)
%FFT
subplot(4,1,2)
ffted=fft(x);
plot(real(ffted));
%FFT Shifted
subplot(4,1,3)
shifted=fftshift(ffted);
plot(real(shifted));
%FFT Shifted by preshifting
subplot(4,1,4)
s=zeros(1,length(x));%In languages like C++ this is computationally inexpesnive
for i=1:length(x)
    if (bitget(i,1))%odd evens, works for real signal
        s(i)=-1;
    else
        s(i)=1;
    end
end
chirpshifted=fft(s.*x);
plot(real(chirpshifted));
%Difference
A=sum(real(chirpshifted));
B=sum(real(shifted));
A
B
```

Comment: So length(x) is 50001?  Does it work with an even length array, but not an odd length?  Probably similar to http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/10250/29  Remember that odd-length ffts are like [DC, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1] while even-length are like [DC, 1, 2, 3, 4 (Nyquist), 3, 2, 1].  The DC component means it's not symmetrical in the obvious way, and odd-length FFTs don't include the Nyquist frequency.  I think inverting every other sample only works for even-length arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple issues with your code. First, let's talk about why you can do what you're trying to do.

What you're trying to take advantage of is the duality between a multiplication in the time domain and convolution in the frequency domain. The `fftshift()` function simply swaps the two halves of a vector (which is assumed to be the result of a call to `fft()`). This operation is equivalent to a circular rotation of half of the vector length in the frequency domain.

One can accomplish the same operation by multiplying by a complex exponential function in the time domain before the FFT, as you noted. To get an $M$-sample shift, you need to multiply by a complex exponential that looks like:

$$
s[n] = e^{\frac{j2\pi nM}{N} }
 $$

For the case where $M = \frac{N}{2}$, this simplifies to:

$$
s[n] = e^{j\pi n} = [1, -1, 1, -1, \ldots]
 $$

This illustrates problem #1 with your script: it multiplies by the inverse of the above: $-s[n]$. You need to invert the sense of the `if` statement in the for loop to ensure that the vector `s` has the appropriate value.

Problem #2 stems from another simple MATLAB mistake: all of the vectors in your simulation are length `50001`. So, the time-domain rotation that you're doing by multiplying by the $s[n]$ illustrated above actually results in an effective frequency domain shift of `25000.5` bins (instead of the `25000`-bin shift implemented by `fftshift()`). The mismatch in results is due to this extra half-bin shift.

You can fix this problem in two ways:

1. Change the time-domain multiplication to multiply by an actual complex exponential vector at the appropriate frequency (i.e. set $M=25000$ and $N=50001$ in the first equation). The resulting signal at the input to the FFT will be complex.
2. Change your simulation to use even-length vectors (i.e. chop off the last element of the `t` vector that you initialize at the beginning).

I tweaked your simulation to fix the generation of `s` and truncate the vector length to `50000`. It is as follows:

```
%1khz
f=1000;
t=0:.0001:5;
t=t(1:length(t)-1);
x=sin(2*pi*f*t);
%Wave
subplot(4,1,1);
plot(x)
%FFT
subplot(4,1,2)
ffted=fft(x);
plot(real(ffted));
%FFT Shifted
subplot(4,1,3)
shifted=fftshift(ffted);
plot(real(shifted));
%FFT Shifted by preshifting
subplot(4,1,4)
s=zeros(1,length(x));%In languages like C++ this is computationally inexpesnive
for i=1:length(x)
    if (~bitget(i,1))%odd evens, works for real signal
        s(i)=-1;
    else
        s(i)=1;
    end
end
chirpshifted=fft(s.*x);
plot(real(chirpshifted));
```

I then compare the results of the two methods:

```
>> diff = abs(chirpshifted-shifted);
>> sum(diff)
ans =

   3.3406e-21
```

As you can see, the results agree as perfectly as you would expect from floating-point math.